# Decode string tag and get id and name

Tags: php, string, tags

```
$cmsstring="<product id="111" /> <video id="222" />  <countdown id="333" />";
```

I want to decode this string and get back related item name and id.

Output will be

```
{
   product,111
   video,222
   countdown,333
}
```

Comment: How this assignment is possible? `$cmsstring="<product id="111" /> <video id="222" />  <countdown id="333" />";`

Comment: client will add this tags in textbox in a Cms entry page .

Comment: Your string _and_ your output have invalid syntax.

Comment: i need dont need output  exact format above , i want to get only all tag name and Id in a loop ,
example , product,productid/video.videoid ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.preg-replace.php) function for this situation.

```
$cmsstring='<product id="111" /> <video id="222" />  <countdown id="333" />';
echo '{' . preg_replace('|<(.*?)\s\id=\"(\d+?)\"\s?\/>|si', '$1 , $2', $cmsstring) . '}' ;
```

Output will be :

```
{product , 111 video , 222  countdown , 333}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Could you please select this answer as "correct".

Answer (score 0):

You can [create DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) from your string, than [find](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) required data from it.

Thanks.